# Renaming a column name, by using the data frame title/name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame called "Something". I am doing an aggregation on one of the numeric columns using summarise, and I want the name of that column to contain "Something" - data frame title in the column name.

Example:

```
    temp <- Something %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise(avg_score=mean(score))
```

But i would like to name the aggregate column as "avg_Something_score". Did that make sense?

Comment: what about `dplyr::rename()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it makes more sense to generate the new column name dynamically so that you don't have to hard-code the name of the data frame inside `setNames`. Maybe something like the function below, which takes a data frame, a grouping variable, and a numeric variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

my_fnc = function(data, group, value) {

  df.name = deparse(substitute(data))

  data %>%
    group_by_(group) %>%
    summarise_(avg = interp(~mean(v), v=as.name(value))) %>%
    rename_(.dots = setNames("avg", paste0("avg_", df.name, "_", value)))
}
```

Now let's run the function on two different data frames:

```
my_fnc(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg")
```

> ```
>     cyl avg_mtcars_mpg
>   <dbl>          <dbl>
> 1     4       26.66364
> 2     6       19.74286
> 3     8       15.10000
> ```

```
my_fnc(iris, "Species", "Petal.Width")
```

> ```
>      Species avg_iris_Petal.Width
> 1     setosa                0.246
> 2 versicolor                1.326
> 3  virginica                2.026
> ```

Comment: Great answer. I think it is a good idea to use standard evaluation for all `dplyr` functions in this case.

Comment: Great answer @eipi10.
this might be too naive, but I am not sure why the functions end in underscores? would it be too much to ask for an explanation on summarise_, and rename_ in the answer code?

Comment: `dplyr` uses [non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). `summarise_`, and other functions with`_`, on the end are the standard evaluation counterparts to the regular `dplyr` functions. You need to use these standard evaluation versions when you want to pass "standard" quoted variable names into dplyr as part of a function call or dynamically change names. I think @akrun's answer uses the same idea, but with a new approach to standard/non-standard evaluation that will be released in the next version of dplyr/tidyverse.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`) that does this with `quosure`s

```
library(dplyr)
myFun <- function(data, group, value){
      dataN <- quo_name(enquo(data))
      group <- enquo(group)
      value <- enquo(value)

      newName <- paste0("avg_", dataN, "_", quo_name(value))
     data %>%
        group_by(!!group) %>%
        summarise(!!newName := mean(!!value))
 }

myFun(mtcars, cyl, mpg)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#   cyl avg_mtcars_mpg
#  <dbl>          <dbl>
#1     4       26.66364
#2     6       19.74286
#3     8       15.10000

myFun(iris, Species, Petal.Width)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#     Species avg_iris_Petal.Width
#     <fctr>                <dbl>
#1     setosa                0.246
#2 versicolor                1.326
#3  virginica                2.026
```

Here, the `enquo` takes the input arguments like `substitute` from `base R` and converts to `quosure`, with `quo_name`, we can convert it to string, evaluate the `quosure` by unquoting (`!!` or `UQ`) inside `group_by/summarise/mutate` etc.  The column names on the lhs of assignment (`:=`) can also evaluated by unquoting to get the columns of interest

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rename_` from `dplyr` with `deparse(substitute(Something))` like this:

```
Something %>%
group_by(Month) %>%
summarise(avg_score=mean(score))%>%
rename_(.dots = setNames("avg_score", 
 paste0("avg_",deparse(substitute(Something)),"_score") ))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

# Take mtcars as an example
# Calculate the mean of mpg using cyl as group
data(mtcars)
Something <- mtcars

# Create a list of expression
dots <- list(~mean(mpg))

# Apply the function, Use setNames to name the column
temp <- Something %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_(.dots =  setNames(dots, 
                               paste0("avg_", as.character(quote(Something)), "_score")))
```

Comment: You brackets closing `as.character` is in the wrong place but otherwise great +1

Comment: @MorganBall Thank you for pointing out the error. I have fixed the position of the closing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use colnames(Something)<-c("score","something_avg_score")