# Get nth, first, or last row of R dataframe conditioned on variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

As nth(y, -1) returns the value not the dataframe and I have no success with row_number() or slice() so far I wonder if I am missing anything obvious or should rethink the approach:

I create a function:

```
ranking <- function(df, state, num = "last"){
    ## Setting num for "last" condition to n() gives error
    num <- ifelse(num=="first", 1, ifelse(num=="last", -1, num)) 
    df %>%
        filter(State == state) %>%
        arrange(y, State) %>%
        slice(num)  ## Does not work for -1
}
```

So for the df below:

```
df <- data.frame(State=c("TX","TX","TX","MD"),y=c(5,2,3,4))
   State y
1     TX 5
2     TX 2
3     TX 3
4     MD 4
```

I want to return the below for the appropriate "last" and nth function call:

```
ranking(df, "TX", "last")
   State y
1     TX 5
ranking(df, "TX", 2)
   State y
1     TX 3
```

Comment: Could you update your question with a better example for the third case as it is not clear to me? i.e. according to your function, 'num' takes values 'first', 'last' and if that is not the case, what should it return as dataset

Comment: Edit shows when num is nth row. Answer from @epi99 works though, I just needed to put the ifelse in the slice so setting last to n() will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
ranking <- function(df, state, num = "last"){
  ## Setting num for "last" condition to n() gives error
  df %>%
    filter(State == state) %>%
    arrange(y) %>%
    slice(ifelse(num=="first", 1, ifelse(num=="last", n(), num)) )
}


df <- data.frame(State=c("TX","TX","TX","MD", "MD"),y=c(5,2,3,4,9))
ranking(df, "TX", "last")
ranking(df, "TX", 2)
ranking(df, "MD", "first")

# State     y
#    TX     5
# State     y
#    TX     3
# State     y
#    MD     4
```

Comment: This works for first and last but not for getting the nth row. Ordering after using top_n and taking the last result might work.

Answer (score 2):

We can change the function slightly and make use of the new `quosure` from the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`)

```
library(dplyr)
rankingN <- function(dat, stateVal, num){

      state <- quo_name(enquo(stateVal))
      num <- quo_name(enquo(num))
       
      numF <- function(x, val) ifelse(x == "first", 1, ifelse(x == "last", val[1], x))
      
      dat %>%
          filter(State == state) %>%
          arrange(y, State) %>%
          mutate(n = n()) %>%
          slice(numF(num, n)) %>%
          select(-n)
 }

rankingN(df, TX, last)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#   State     y
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     TX     5

rankingN(df, TX, first)    
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#   State     y
#   <fctr> <dbl>
#1     TX     2

rankingN(df, MD, first)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#    State     y
#    <fctr> <dbl>
#1     MD     4
```

---

Or another option is to do a double `slice` to return two rows in the first `slice` and then select the first or last one based on the `case_when` function return

```
rankingN1 <- function(dat, stateVal, num){
            
        state <- quo_name(enquo(stateVal))
        num <- quo_name(enquo(num))
        numF <- function(x) case_when(x == "first" ~1L, 
                                      x== "last" ~2L,
                                      TRUE ~NA_integer_)
         dat %>%
            filter(State == state) %>%
            arrange(y, State) %>%
            slice(c(1, n())) %>%
            slice(numF(num))

 }



rankingN1(df, TX, last)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#   State     y
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     TX     5

rankingN1(df, TX, first)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#   State     y
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     TX     2
 rankingN1(df, MD, first)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#   State     y
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     MD     4
```

The `enquo` takes the input arguments and convert to `quosure`, while `quo_name` converts it to string for places where it is required as string evaluation.  Instead of using `n()` inside the `ifelse`, we create a column based on it and then `slice` the rows based on the values returned from that column

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(State=c("TX","TX","TX","MD"),y=c(5,2,3,4))
```

Comment: The use of quosures is very interesting. I think I'll need to get used to it, but it is really nice.

Comment: @FlorianGD Yes, it is very convenient way of passing variables in functions.  Previously, `interp` and other stuffs were required.  Now, it is easy to even name the columns by passing variables without setNames or rename like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546765/renaming-a-column-name-by-using-the-data-frame-title-name)